# Generate War file using Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a maven pom as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MerchantWallet</groupId>
  <artifactId>StellarReceive</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>StellarReceive Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- hello -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>StellarReceive</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I dont see a .war file in the target folder. Can someone please help

Here is my folder structure: 
[image]

Comment: when you `run as...` -> `maven install`, do you see any warnings or errors?

Comment: Please add more information about how you are running Maven.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First you must define your project with as packaging of war type:

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<version>...</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Then you will need to use the maven plugin to generate the war when compiling:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Funny side note: IntelliJ IDEA (v2019.2) does not do code assistance for the war plugin syntax if you're missing `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml

Comment: does there a CLI option ?

Answer (score 3):

Try running `clean install` or `clean package` maven command.

Project > run as > run config > maven build in left panel > right click > new > goal > `clean install` > base directory> select your current project workspace.> apply> run

same way for `clean package` or any other maven command.

if it gives `BUILD SUCCESS` then fine otherwise put that error code here in the question.

Answer (score 2):

one solution is just to use a maven-war-plugin(https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html)