# Exclude maven dependency from build

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Ive two maven projects. Project A and Project B. B uses A as a dependency. When I build B as a war, Maven exports A and it's dependency. How to tell maven not to include this dependency tree alone while exporting?  I cannot find excludes tag in maven war configuration.

Note: I cannot use provided scope in the dependency because I need it to test using embedded tomcat.

Snippet of Project B Pom

```
<dependencies>
<!-- Project A -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <port>80</port>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Exclude Tag is not available in configuration -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>  
  </plugins>
```

Comment: You can create two profiles, one for embedded tomcat and another for provided,  put your dependency in the tomcat profile as rubtime and in the other as provided.

Comment: Does this solve your issue friend? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297430/generate-war-file-using-maven

Comment: Thanks @Arturo looks like that's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve finally decided to clone a branch in git and call it release branch. It’ll now have a different Pom i.e., scope of project A within B will be provided. After series of changes in the Dev branch, I’ll cherry pick it into release branch and build the jars. Also I believe this should be good for Jenkins (haven’t tested yet, but that’s next)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create profiles, you can create two profiles, one for development (embedded tomcat, with dep A), and another for production (without the dep)

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- dep A -->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- dep A -->
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```