# Facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, servlets

I'm getting this error while starting server:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

My pom.xml file content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ccc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ccc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ccc</name>
  <description>ccc</description>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opengeo/geodb -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opengeo</groupId>
            <artifactId>geodb</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.vorburger.mariaDB4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariaDB4j</artifactId>
            <version>${mariaDB4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>${openjdk-jmh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- spring related jars below this line -->
        
        <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
            programming implementation allowing you to define -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
            Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
            for web applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
            such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
            IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org.springframework.transaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org.springframework.beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


<!--  spring jars above this line-->
            
        <!--  javax jar to remove issue with jsp file -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>    -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.19.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.21</mysql.version>
        <mariaDB4j.version>2.2.3</mariaDB4j.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.8.0</assertj-core.version>
        <openjdk-jmh.version>1.21</openjdk-jmh.version>
        <geodb.version>0.9</geodb.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  
</project>
```

Points taken care from my end regarding dependency:

1. Maven dependency add to deployment assembly.
2. All spring-framework jars are of same version.
3. Tomcat 9.0 selected in runtime in Project facets.
4. mvn clean install - Build success.
5. mvn eclipse:eclipse  - Build sucess.
6. cleaned .m2/repository and updated maven.

My web.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ccc</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Points taken care regarding web.xml:

1. Web app id is 3.1 in Project facets.
2. jsp files are inside WEB-INF/view
3. home.jsp file is placed at WEB-INF
4. jars which should be placed at WEB-INF/lib are directed using deployment assembly. Have added maven dependency there. Hence WEB-INF/lib not created.

These are my insights on the issues I am facing. I have tried all other solutions provided in stackoverflow.com , youtube.com and other websites.

Update:

1. As requested adding error stack.
2. adding jars to WEB-INF/lib is not necessary I guess, since I am using maven to do the same in deployment assembly! Correct and guide me if I am wrong.

Below is the error stack:

```
  SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/ccc] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1042)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4864)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:738)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

Comment: There are many reasons leading to this problem，can you provide more error messages？Or try putting the JAR in the lib directory.

Comment: You seem to be missing `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your POM, see also [Generate War file using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297430/generate-war-file-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Right click project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add
2. Choose Java Build Path Entries -> Maven dependencies.
3. Force update maven and Redeploy maven project on tomcat
4. Restart Tomcat.

We need to point Java build path to Maven dependencies as tomcat not aware of your build operations. By default It will find JAR from WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: NiravHR I have tried Maven dependency in deployment assembly..  please refer list of things I have taken care above.  Let me know if I am missing any..

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml under version tag add this:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

If you are using embedded tomcat in pom.xml under dependencies then add this

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```