# Publish soap service in a server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, soap

I have developed a soap web service in Java and the public through a virtual server as follows:

`Endpoint.publish (" http: // localhost: 2021 / soap / Person ", new ServiceImpl ());`

When I run the code, the web service is published to the address and port that I indicated in the previous statement. In SoapUI I import the WSDL and I can consume the operations of the service correctly.

What I want to do now is host my web service on a server to publish it in a real way and that I could access it from another machine. I understand that I have to host it on a Tomcat server, but I don't know the steps I have to follow, nor have I found much information about it. Can somebody help me?

Thanks

All the best

Comment: Hey, what Build-Tool are you using? Gradle? Maven?

Comment: Im using maven.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a WAR-File from your project. You can for example use `mvn package` for that if you are using maven. The WAR-File will be placed in the target directory of your project.
If you are having trouble [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297430/generate-war-file-using-maven) might help.

After that you can install a tomcat on a hosted server, or you try to install tomcat locally on your machine to get comfortable.

Then you deploy your WAR-File to your tomcat by visiting `http://localhost:8080/manager` and uploading your file.

[This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war) covers other ways of deploying to tomcat and has useful information on necessary configuration.